# Why does an angular $http call that fails repeat itself infinitely?

Tags: angularjs

I have:

```
this.isAuthenticated = function() {
  var deferred;
  deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    url: "" + endpoints.authService + "api/v1/session/check",
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true
  }).success(function(response) {
    var user;
    if (response.authenticated === true) {
      user = response;
    }
    return deferred.resolve(response);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.reject(data);
    return $rootScope.$broadcast('api-error', 'Cannot access authentication service');
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Assuming that the endpoint is down, apparently it tries to do the call infinitely. Is this some known Angular behavior? And can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No factory making http call when your controller invoking that call please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/u7YSD8gkbOSKN32SU62P?p=preview. It's rather you controller keeping call factory function.

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q, $rootScope) {
      var endpoints = {
        authService: "ttest"
      };
      this.isAuthenticated = function() {
        var deferred;
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
          url: "" + endpoints.authService + "api/v1/session/check",
          method: 'GET',
          withCredentials: true
        }).success(function(response) {
          var user;
          if (response.authenticated === true) {
            user = response;
          }
          return deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.reject(data);
          return $rootScope.$broadcast('api-error', 'Cannot access authentication service');
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      };

      return this;
    });

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

      $scope.$on('api-error', function(a, b){
       alert(b);
     });


 dataService.isAuthenticated();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just put this `deferred.resolve(response);` instead of `return deferred.resolve(response);`

and also remove return from  :

```
return $rootScope.$broadcast('api-error', 'Cannot access authentication service');
```

Comment: I don't think that'll do it. I'm actually writing in `CoffeeScript` so that's the translated code